# Chrome + webkit translate3d, mangles images

Tags: image, google-chrome, webkit, translate3d, visual-glitch

This is a bit weird. When I apply `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` to images on a site I am building, they look fine initially. But when I start scrolling or resize the browser window to above a certain size (roughly past 1200x1024) the images get all glitched up, containing parts of other images, or of the site. All stretched, cut up. Sometimes even change color and whatnot. This also applies to the @font-face text that is floating above the images. I assume this is very isolated case in combination with Win7x64/ATI Firepro v5800/Chrome version. But its a bit annoying to build a site this way :)

Anyone came across a similar issue and knows how to solve it, or should i just notify google of this?

Comment: Might be related to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953497/webkit-transform-overwrites-z-index-ordering-in-chrome-13

There's a work around there.