# Input field leaving artifacts from CSS3 transition (in Chrome 15)

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/danielcgold/SYgzJ/

When you click on the input then go on blur, artifacts are left on the screen in Chrome 15. I first noticed this issue on a site i've been developing so I eliminated everything but just the input field and a button. When I remove the button, the transition happens just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a chrome rendering bug.

Comment: I have it also without the button, weird

Comment: Definitely a Redraw / Repaint bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this CSS to your input field:

```
input {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
}
```

This will force Chrome to use your GPU to do all the rendering which will solve the artifacts problem and make your animations smother.

Comment: This worked. When I applied this property to my style block where I set all my transitions, it broke something in my layout. I just set this property through a class and it worked!

Comment: This can cause another problem: z-index could be messed up. [See here to handle it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953497/webkit-transform-overwrites-z-index-ordering-in-chrome-13).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Chrome's rendering of CSS transitions. But you can workaround it by forcing element "refresh" operation. Please note that you need to refresh not the `input` element, but it's parent, so the following code will help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').blur(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass('repaint');
    });
    $('#test').focus(function(){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('repaint');
    });
});
```

And `repaint` class should have something related to parent's view, for example different color:

```
.repaint {
 color: red;
}
```

But you may replace `color` with `visibility` or other view-related (but not important/visible for parent) attribute.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSYfX/3/) to demonstrate the workaround

Comment: This did not work, I tried applying class to animated element as well as body using the `jQuery` callback as well as `promise().done()` The `translate3d` solution did work...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with box shadow artifacts in Safari, and found adding `-webkit-transform:scale(1);` to the focus rule fixed the problem.

See http://jsfiddle.net/SYgzJ/48/ – it should work fine now.

As Cesar said, `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` will fix it, but it can affect text rendering too.