# Can css3 translateZ() be used instead of z-index?

Tags: css, css-transforms, translate3d

For example having 2 div's positioned absolute, one can put first div upon second by setting first div's z-index higher than second one's. 
Can we achieve such behaviour using translateZ() or  translate3d?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer now, 3 years after, is that you can.
You need to use `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the parent, [but it's possible](https://jsfiddle.net/67h5fe4e/).

```css
.container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.test1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}
.test2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  left: 250px;
  top: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test1">
    test
  </div>

  <div class="test2">
    test #2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, marked this answer as accepted. It is worth noting that both envolved elements should have `transform` property applied.

Comment: Hey. Can you take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/KT6raJ3rBgq8aO1y8Xlk)? The button is hidden despite having greater translate z value. Thanks.

Comment: Hm. I’m getting a big red square in Chrome 58 and Safari 10.1.

Comment: Oh, wait. Is that what I’m meant to get?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it was defined... :)

Comment: FYI: this doesn't seem to work if `.container` has `overflow: hidden;` applied

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: **No**. [View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nN55y/) which works as of time of posting

Longer answer: **It's not supposed to**, but sometimes, such as when one element has a transform when its sibling doesn't, some browsers [don't handle the situation well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953497/webkit-transform-overwrites-z-index-ordering-in-chrome-13), resulting in the z-index being ignored.

Generally, however, this is because the `transform` itself is applied, not because of the `translateZ`. The solution in such a case it to give all relevant elements `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` or something similar which makes the browser render the elements more carefully