# Difference between z-index and translateZ()

Tags: css, transform, z-index

what is the difference between the `z-index` and `transform:translateZ();` in css

Answer (score 2):

The [`z-index`-property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) is supposed to be a measure of stacking positioned elements while [`translateZ()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ) is supposed to be animated and transitioned to move objects in the 3d-space.

They can  be used interchangeably **in some scenarios** which you can learn more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977220/can-css3-translatez-be-used-instead-of-z-index).

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property allows you to set the order of the stack where any greater number assigned to it will just bring it in front of the other element whereas `transform:transitionz()` will actually decide the distance by which the element will be farther from another elements on z-axis.